# C Program to sum a simple series

Tags: c

I have a program here that is supposed to sum up the series 
1+1/2+1/3+1/4... etc

The only user entry is to enter how many times you want this sum to run for.
However, I keep getting the sum one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
    {
        int b,x; /* b is number of times program runs and x is the count*/
        float sum;
        printf("Enter the number of times you want series to run.\n");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        printf("x     sum\n");

        for(x=1,sum=0;x<b+1;x++)
        {
          printf("%d %9.3f\n",x, (sum +=(float)(1/x)));
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

I don't quite get why it isn't working. As you can see, I did tell it to print x and when it did, x was incrementing correctly.The sum just kept adding up to one.

Comment: Try to print out `(float)(1/x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misplaced parentheses so you're doing integer division for `1/x` and getting 0 for any value of x > 1.

I suggest you change:

```
      printf("%d %9.3f\n",x, (sum +=(float)(1/x)));
```

to:

```
      printf("%d %9.3f\n",x, (sum += 1.0f/x));
```

Comment: Well it seems most of you got to this fast... either way.. I guess you were the first one to answer it correctly.. dunno why it won't let me... And yeah.. I see that now.. oops.

Comment: You'll still get (systematically) an understated result due to floating point imprecision. See my answer ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's a separate problem, but you're correct that reversing the loop order will give better numerical stability.

Comment: @Paul R; yes you're correct; OP complains that the sum is always one and your answer fixes that. But I spend so much of my day job fixing problems due to misuse of floating point, I can't help myself.

Answer (score 4):

Two problems: one dull, one interesting.

1) `1 / x` will be imprecise since 1 and x are both integral types and so the computation will be done in integer arithmetic. All the cast does is convert the resultant integral type to floating point. To resolve this, write `1.0 / x`. Then 'x' is promoted to floating point prior to the division.

2) **You should reverse the order of the `for` loop**:

```
 sum = 0.0;
 for(x = b; x >= 1; --x)
```

(I've also moved the initialisation or `sum` from the for loop as `sum = 0` is an expression of type `float` but `x = b` is an expression of type `int` so you ought not use the comma operator as they have different data types.)

The reason is subtle: you should only add floating points of similar magnitude. Doing the loop my way means the smaller values are added first.

The effect will be noticeable for high values of `b`; try it. Your original way will always understate the sum.

Comment: But I am not adding floating points in the for loop so do I really need to change that?

Comment: You add them here: sum +=(float)(1/x).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is integer division when you do `1/x`, which always result in 0 as long as `x` is greater than 1. Even it you later convert this to a `float`, the "damage" is already done. An easy fix would be to change the division to `1.0f/x`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have declared x as an int, (1/x) returns 1 when x is 1 and 0 for x>1. So, sum remains 1. So you get the same result.

So, change `(1/x)` to `1.0f/x`, so that the result is returned as a float

Answer (score 1):

Here you are computing `1/x` in which the fractional value is truncated. Converting it into float after the original value has been truncated doesn't make sense.

So change this to:-

```
printf("%d %9.3f\n",x, (sum +=(float)(1/x)));
```

to

```
printf("%d %9.3f\n",x, (sum += 1.0f/x));
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(1/x)` will always be integer division. For the first run this will be `1/1` giving you 1. However, next time round it will be `1/2` which is 0. Basically for `1/x` where x>1 the answer will be zero.

To get around this write the expression as `1.0/x` which will cause `x` to be promoted to a double, giving you double division.